# how to apply the background image and text color for cell in the tableview?

Tags: iphone

hi all how is the TableView code for applying  background image and text color white to the cell not for tableview it is only for cell give me the solution in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Custom Cell class

```
@interface CellView : UITableViewCell
{
    UIImageView *img;
    UILabel *lblTitle;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
@end
```

And in the implementation

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustCell *cell=(CustCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *arr=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id idCell in arr){

            if([idCell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell=(CustCell *) idCell;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.lbl.text=[arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.jpg"];
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a subview to *cell.contentView* containing your image for background.
To set the color of the text, you can do

```
[cell.textLabel setTextColor: your_color];
```

Answer (score 0):

//To set backgroud image

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"]]];
```

//To set Text color

```
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```